# Make Windows 7 to drive a DVI-I port with a TMDS signal

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, dvi

I have an AMD Radeon R9 380 with three monitors connected to the DisplayPort, DVI-D and DVI-I port of the graphics card. The monitors are all equal and have a DisplayPort and DVI-D port each, i.e. they expect a digital TMDS signal.

This setup works flawlessly under Linux.

However, under Windows 7 the monitor that is connected to the DVI-I port stays dark. In the system settings the presence of a third monitor is detected but shown as an unknown monitor. I can tick a checkbox "Force VGA signal" but of course this does not help, because the VGA pins are not connected.

It seems that Windows 7 (or the AMD driver) is confined to only deliver a VGA signal through the DVI-I port. I know the graphic card can do both (analog and TMDS) on that port, because it works under Linux.

This issue also exist if I only connect a single monitor to the DVI-I port, i.e. the issue is not specific to the multi-monitor setup.

Where is the option to tell Windows 7 (or the driver) to output TMDS over the DVI-I port?

Comment: You are running the newest AMD driver, right?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry, I did not mentioned that I thought this would be obvious.